# нахождение произведения элементов массива между первым и вторым нулевыми элементами

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        result = 1;
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfEl; i++)
        {
            if (FirstMass[i] == 0)
            {
                while (i + j < NumOfEl && FirstMass[i + j] != 0)
                {
                    result *= FirstMass[i + j];
                }
            }
        }
```

вот мой код, размер массива вводится с клавиатуры, а элемент задаются случайно.
Первый нулевой - первый элемент со значением 0

Вопрос состоит в том, что я неправильно делаю, и как сделать правильно? 
Я понимаю, что задача выполняется в 2 цикла, но я уже 3 часа получаю index is out of range.

Comment: Stackoverflow - формат базы знаний в виде "вопрос - ваш пример - описание - ответ(от случая к случаю)". Пример есть. Описания нет. Вопроса нет. Дополните вопрос.
Так же непонятно, что за "первый и второй нулевой элемент". Распишите подробнее. Представьте, что вам нужно объяснить задачу ребенку или человеку, не в контексте вашей задачи. Будет ли вам понятна такая формулировка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно за один проход [ideone](https://ideone.com/ly9IZO):

```
int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 9 };

bool is_multiplied = false;
long result = 0;

int index = 0;
while (index < data.Length)
{
    if (data[index] == 0)
    {
        is_multiplied = !is_multiplied;

        if (!is_multiplied)
        {
            break;
        }

        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_multiplied)
        {
            result *= data[index];
        }
    }

    index++;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);  // 2520
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу вам нужно перемножить элементы массива с первого 0 элемента и до второго 0 элемента? Тогда примерно так:

```
private int SomeMthod()
    {
        int[] firstMass = new int[] { 1, 5, 0, 8, 4, 9, 0, 8 };
        int result = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < firstMass.Length; i++)
        {
            if (firstMass[i] == 0)
            {
                MultiplyElements(firstMass, i + 1, ref result);
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void MultiplyElements(int[] firstMass, int index, ref int result)
    {
        if (firstMass[index] == 0 || index == firstMass.Length)
        {
            return;
        }

        result *= firstMass[index];

        MultiplyElements(firstMass, index + 1, ref result);
    }
```